# I am bot able to edit the js file at runtime using chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I tried to save the changes by inserting breakpoints and tried to reload the page,And added by changes in the form of alert messages but still the newly added alerts aren't visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the changes (Ctrl + S) you made to apply them, make sure you apply the changes before the code is executed (with a breakpoint)

Answer (score 0):

the javascript is most likely cached by your browser and the new one is not being downloaded.

click Control +R in your browser to do a "strong refresh" it will redownload the website and the new js file

Comment: He want's to change the code in the chrome-debugger so a cache-reset isn't necessary